# ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта с#

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда пытаюсь запустить этот код в двух потоках вылезает такая ошибка, как ее исправить ?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю у Вас обращение к элементу интерфейса (textBox2) из другого потока

Comment: Замените картинку в вопросе кодом как текст.